# MRTK hand gesture not working in HoloLens 2 Unity app after putting the headset away for a while

Tags: hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

Start app - hand gestures for near interaction grabbable works at intended. Able to move and resize virtual object.

Headset off for 10 minutes while leaving the app open.

Put headset on again - the said hand gestures stop working. Wrist menu gesture still works, so I think hand gestures are still being recognized, but the position of the virtual object within the environment is not being established properly.

Wait for 5 minutes - hand gestures works again.

My best guess is that when the headset is put away and back on again, inside-out tracking needs time to start working again.

Anyone can think of a solution to solve this issue without the wait for 5 minutes or relaunching the app?

Thanks!

Additional notes: The environment I am using the HoloLens in is rather plain (wall without decorations or accent), and therefore it might give inside-out tracking a hard time. I tested putting the HoloLens off and on in a well-decorated environment, and found that the hand gestures always worked even with the HoloLens put away (while the camera facing the well-decorated environment).